# No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python3, numpy, matplotlib

Actually I am shifting from Windows to Linux. Using pycharm on Windows I have a python 3 script that requires numpy and matplotlib to run, so I installed them on my Linux system using

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
sudo apt-get install matplotlib3-numpy
```

But still when I try to run the script I get error:

```
from python3-numpy import  *
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

or:

```
from numpy import  *
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: do you try sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib    before sudo apt-get install python3-numpy??

Comment: yes @NadimulDeCj, retyping it says - "python-matplotlib is already the newest version."

Comment: Are you sure you don't use python to run the file with "from numpy import *"? Many computers link python to Python 2.7 and python3 to Python 3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install numpy using pip

 install pip :

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
```

Then install numpy using pip

```
sudo pip3 install -U numpy
```

Comment: from Ubuntu 20.04+ avoid installing  `python-pip` as python3 is default with no python 2.x

Comment: This doesn't answer why? Shouldn't I be able to access system-installed packages assuming I'm not running in a virtual env or some other type of isolation tool?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you run python3 and not just python, which defaults to python2.7 on most systems.

You can get the Version of python with

```
python --version
```

or

```
python3 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other answer didn't work for you, try:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
sudo pip install numpy; sudo pip3 install numpy
```

If that doesn't work, then you have other issues.

Answer (score 0):

same issue I faced. I installed and uninstalled numpy from terminal but didn't work for pycharm. I found that my issue was with the environment I created in Pycharm. Most likely package isn't installed.

just install it on your current env follow below steps. I'm using Mac and should be the same on other OS:

1. go to preference
2. under project, click on project interpreter
3. then you'll see all packages you installed. if you don't see numpy, just click on the plus sign and search then install. it should work now

Good luck